# How to call my extension method to detect written annotation?

Tags: php, c++, zephir, php-cpp

Hi i'm tring to write an extension for php in zephir or php-cpp to call my customMethod from my extention when comment block like code below added to php file any suggestion note will be appreciate

```
<?php 
/* myNotation:my comment */ 
echo "Hello World"
?>
```

if comment like this added to source when source fired it should be detect that notation **myNotation** is presented in comment and has value as **my comment**

here is my sample extension cpp file

```
 /**
 *  myExtention.cpp
 * 
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <phpcpp.h>

/**
 *  Namespace to use
 */
using namespace std;

/**
 *  HelloWorldEcho()
 *  echo parameter.
 *  @param      &params
 */
void HelloWorldEcho(Php::Parameters &params)
{
    cout << "Your Comment" << params<< endl;
}


// Symbols are exported according to the "C" language
extern "C" 
{
    // export the "get_module" function that will be called by the Zend engine
    PHPCPP_EXPORT void *get_module()
    {
        // create extension
        static Php::Extension extension("myExtention","1.0");

        // add function to extension
        extension.add<HelloWorldEcho>("HelloWorldEcho", {
            Php::ByVal("x", Php::Type::String)
            });

        // return the extension module
        return extension.module();
    }
}
```

and now when my extension compiled and added to php extensions then i can call it from php file like this

```
<?php
/**
 *  HelloWorldEcho.php
 * 
 *  An example file to show the working of a php function call in C++.
 */

HelloWorldEcho("my comment");
```

The main question is that how can i call my extension method **call_php_function** when i have comment like code below and pass my comment as parameter to my method:

```
<?php 
/* myNotation:my comment */ 
echo "Hello World"
?>
```